# Tensorflow gpu version running out of memory with 16GB RAM and 8 GB GPU Nvidia Quadro M4000

Tags: tensorflow, windows-7-x64

I am working on tensorflow using GPU a Nvidia Quadro M4000 8GB graphic card.
I am having a issue of memory error. I have tried using memory growth method but still facing the same.

```
ResourceExhaustedError: OOM when allocating tensor with shape[1,64,1228,1029]
```

here the shape [1,64,1228,1029] comes after the first pooling layer

Everything is been installed on Windows 7:

- python3.5.2
- virtualenv
- cuda toolkit 8.0
- cudnn 5.1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, as this is only 323 megabytes only allocating this tensor should not be the only problem.

Try to see what other tensors you are allocating in your program. Most likely you are allocating many of this size, or many others somewhere in your program.

Another problem you might have is that you are running multiple programs at the same time. Try running the `nvidia-smi` equivalent in Windows to see how much memory your card is using at the moment.

Comment: thanks for the help
yes my program is allocating similar tensor of almost same size 
i have a network of 3conv layer 3 max pool 2x2 pool layer and one fully connected layer for the images of size 2456*2058

Comment: Pro-tip here would be to start small. It actually fits on your computer, you get way quicker feedback so you can make changes, etc... I don't know how your conv layers look like, but I suspect them to be very large ;) Try to start with something small, if you get good results, build bigger.

Comment: Thanks for the tip , And Surly i will try first with smaller version of the model then i will take it to the next step.
thanks alot @rmeertens

Comment: one more help
how did you calculated that its 323 MB only.

Comment: @AKSHAYMANKAR tensor of shape [a,b,c,d] and type float32 (32 bits). So, 323 comes from: a*b*c*d*(bits to mb = 1bit is 1.25x10-7)